# /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash : No such file or directory found

Tags: ros, installation, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Noetic on my Virtualbox with UBUNTU 20.04. Every time I run this command: source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash. I get the above mentioned error. I have tried removing this line from .bashrc file..(was not there...I added it and then removed it...no difference). The problem is I cannot find setup.bash file anywhere. Also I reinstalled by making new folder and opening it terminal. Still no difference. This setup file does not seems to be downloaded or the directory is completely unknown,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374855//opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash-:-no-such-file-or-directory-found/) by [Tatsat](https://answers.ros.org/users/72598/tatsat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-29**:
If that file can't be found, I'd make sure you've correctly installed ROS.

What's the output of `dpkg -l | grep ros-noetic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, thank you for the reply. Yes you are correct. It was not installed correctly. I ran: sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full  .... again and the problem got solved.

---

Originally posted by [Tatsat](https://answers.ros.org/users/72598/tatsat/) with karma: 16 on 2021-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0